# How to delete/remove manually apt added repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

Please help me: I added this repositories manually and i cant remove them

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/Debian_8.0/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vertex-theme.list

wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:Horst3180/Debian_8.0/Release.key
```

I tried to use removing the key using `apt-key list` and then removing using the id, it successfully removed the key but when i use `apt update` i get this output:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/Debian_8.0  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/Debian_8.0  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I just want to be able to run `apt update` normally like when a fresh OS install was made

Comment: I also would like to know if running an 'apt dist-upgrade' would fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the created `.list` file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vertex-theme.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vertex-theme.list.save
```

After that run and update and maybe even a dist upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Since you already removed the key you have nothing more to do.